# How to do Template based source file generation in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

In our application there is a module for source code file generation based on templates. The generated source codes are  Python, PHP, SQL etc.  I found this post [How to create Template based files in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055073/how-to-create-template-based-files-in-java) but the solution is for Java. Is there any libraries available for .net ?

Comment: Have you considered T4? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx

Comment: This might be of interest: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/867045/Csharp-Based-Template-Transformation-Engine

Answer (score 0):

There is a version of Mustache for .NET as well, check out for the library.

Github: https://github.com/jehugaleahsa/mustache-sharp

NuGet: http://www.nuget.org/packages/mustache-sharp

Hope that helps, I've used it a few times, it's pretty straight forward and works well.

Comment: Oh, one other library that's similar to Mustache is Handlebars, which provides some slightly added functionality, there is a .NET version of it as well, just search Google for it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555820/what-are-the-differences-between-mustache-js-and-handlebars-js